# Column Values shifting to next row while creating a CSV using SQL *Plus

Tags: oracle, csv, sh, export-to-csv, sql-loader

I want the output of a SQL query in a csv file. While other such jobs are running successfully, here is a job, one of them, which gives me a csv like this. I have checked the loader control file - it seems fine. I have also checked the SQL query - also, perfectly fine. What could be the problem?

[image]

```
SPOOL CSV_TO_BE_GENERATED.csv;
SET LINESIZE 1000;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE

 select 
'COLUMN_1'||','||
'COLUMN_2'||','||
'COLUMN_3'||','||
'COLUMN_4'||','||
'COLUMN_5'||','||
'COLUMN_6'||','||
'COLUMN_7'||','||
'COLUMN_8'
 from DUAL;

 select COLUMN_1||','||
 COLUMN_2||','||
 COLUMN_3||','||
 COLUMN_4||','||
 COLUMN_5||','||
 COLUMN_5||','||
 COLUMN_7||','||
 COLUMN_8  
 from some_table ;

 SPOOL OFF
 EXIT;
```

Comment: How are you generating the CSV? From SQL*Plus? I don't follow where SQL*Loader fits in here. Perhaps you could show the comands and queries/scripts you are using.

Comment: Yes, @AlexPoole - Querying Using SQL *Plus. SQL *Loader loads the csv into the table.

Comment: This could be anything; for instance you're opening this in Excel, which could just be parsing the data incorrectly. What do you see if you open it in a text editor? You might have stray line terminators in your data, or you may not have properly escaped double quotes. I'm unsure how you're "creating" a csv with SQL*Loader as well...

Comment: @Ben - I have phrased the question incorrectly. I have explained what I am doing with SQL *Plus and what I am doing with SQL *Loader. Ignore the misleading question. Now that I have explained the problem. I have also attached the code.

Comment: My points weren't about your code but about your _data_ @Monty...

Comment: @Ben - I've attached the snapshot of the data I am getting in the csv (opened in Excel)

Comment: If you'd bothered to read my comment you'd have realised that opening in Excel could easily be the problem... Excel automatically converts files into a readable format for itself and is not an accurate representation of the data.

Comment: @Ben - Which is why, I had already checked the file in TextPad and jEdit. The last two columns are moving to the next row.

Comment: You stil aren't helping us help you. 'Moving to the next row'... when you view the `.csv` in TextPad too, or only when opened in Excel? Since you seem to be changing the data for the question (presumably to hide sensitive things) it's impossible to tell what you really have - whether there are line breaks, commas in the data, ... basically what Ben said a while ago.

Comment: I've checked for line breaks, and commas already. Is there anything else that I can look for? @AlexPoole - Thanks for understanding, yes, the data is sensitive. Cannot share it here.